# "Unknown extension pipelining" message when sending mail from Emacs

Tags: email, emacs

I see "Unknown extension pipelining" in my *Messages* buffer, after sending an email with Emacs.  I am wondering what is this telling me?  I've done a couple of searches in the lisp source code and haven't seen where this message is generated.  Can someone explain the origin of this message?

My email is sent successfully.  I include below lines from the *Messages* buffer and also from the buffer "*trace of SMTP session to localhost*".  I am queuing the mail before sending it.  My setup is

GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) of 2011-03-10 on 3249CTO

and I have Cygwin routines in use.

from *Messages* buffer:

> Loading c:/cygwin/home/Mail/queued-mail/2012-04-25_11!18!51_2.el (source)...done
>   220 smtp107.sbc.mail.mud.yahoo.com ESMTP
>   250-smtp107.sbc.mail.mud.yahoo.com
>   250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XYMCOOKIE
>   250-PIPELINING
>   250 8BITMIME
>   Unknown extension pipelining
>   235 OK, go ahead
>   250 OK , completed [2 times]
>   354 Start Mail. End with CRLF.CRLF
>   250 OK , completed
>   221 Service Closing transmission
>   Wrote c:/cygwin/home/Mail/queued-mail/index

from buffer *trace of SMTP session to localhost*:

> Process SMTP deleted
>   220 smtp107.sbc.mail.mud.yahoo.com ESMTP
>
> EHLO DELLLAPTOP
>
> 250-smtp107.sbc.mail.mud.yahoo.com
>
> 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XYMCOOKIE
>
> 250-PIPELINING
>
> 250 8BITMIME
>
> AUTH PLAIN [deleted]
>
> 235 OK, go ahead
>
> MAIL FROM:
>
> 250 OK , completed

Answer (score 2):

A standard part of an SMTP session is the client saying EHLO and the server responding with its name followed by a list of supported SMTP extensions.  The client can then choose to use or not use the listed extensions during the SMTP session.

The Emacs SMTP package smtpmail.el that you're using has an option to warn about SMTP extensions that the server offers in EHLO that the Emacs client doesn't support.  This is an option primarily meant for developer use and so should not be enabled by default.  Apparently it is enabled in your Emacs session, hence you see the warning about PIPELINING.

```
(setq smtpmail-warn-about-unknown-extensions nil)
```

in your .emacs file should get rid of the warnings.